# Cylinder position and speed control

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control

I have cylinder model that I control with 4/3 directional valve. When 4/3DV control input is 10V, cylinder moves forward and when valves control input is -10V, then cylinder moves backward. I can get any data from cylinder(position, speed, acceleration,force).

Now I want to make control system for this. I would like to make control system that I can set target position and target speed for system. I could use PID controller, but what parameter to control?

Just asking what is the best way to make this kind of control system, be fore I start to make it.

Comment: The output of the PID cannot be anything other than the voltage unless the output is again passed through another controller.

Comment: Yes, that what the end will be. But I can't give PID controller just position and/or speed and then the output would be voltages?

Answer (score 1):

When using a 4/3 directional valve your control options are very limited forward, off or backward.

A PID controller will make no sense, since its has an output which is a finite number.

The only controller you can use is a 3-state controller

[image: 3-state controller]

To understand, create and use a 3-state feedbackcontroller, you should read the section "In engineering" on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis which explains it for a 2-state controller i.e. on/off controller.
And for the 3-state feedbackcontroller: http://www.jumo.de/en_DE/support/faq/controllers/T2/Q6.html.